# xml2code lib generates `string` type from `positiveInteger`

Tags: c#, xsd

I'm using `xml2code` library to convert `xsd` file to C# code.

In `Generator.xs` file, the following code is mapping the xsd types to C# types:

```
var importer = new XmlSchemaImporter(schemas, generationOptions, new ImportContext(new CodeIdentifiers(), false));

foreach (XmlSchemaType type in xsd.Items.OfType<XmlSchemaType>())
{
    var mapping = importer.ImportSchemaType(type.QualifiedName);
    exporter.ExportTypeMapping(mapping);
}
```

All types are mapped pretty good, except `positiveInteger` (from the namespace "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema").

I've tried to fix it from code, somthing like:

```
switch (mapping.XsdTypeName)
{
    case "positiveInteger":
        mapping.TypeFullName = "System.UInt32"; // was "System.String"
        mapping.TypeName = "UInt32";            // was "String"
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

but unfortunately all `XmlTypeMapping` properties are read only, so I can't event create a new instance to send to the function `exporter.ExportTypeMapping()`.

I have no idea how to change the mapped type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that Microsoft `XmlSchemaImportersd` library (inside `System.Xml.Serialization`), is mapping the following types to `String`:

```
negativeInteger
nonNegativeInteger
nonPositiveInteger
positiveInteger
```

So to force `XmlSchemaImportersd` to map into a C# base types you need to use the following `xs:` types instaed:

```
byte
decimal
int
integer
long
short
unsignedLong
unsignedInt
unsignedShort
unsignedByte
```